# Select diferentes condições para a mesma coluna

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Tenho a seguinte Tabela com minha consulta atual.

```
Data        |  PesoTotal
01/04/2019  |  500         
02/04/2019  |  800
```

E eu gostaria de acrescentar uma nova coluna (PesoHorario), que seria o Peso na data, porém antes das 8 da manhã.

Consigo fazer as consultas separadamente, porém, quando tento fazer em uma consulta, os valores são distorcidos da realidade.

**CONSULTA APENAS COM O PESOHORARIO**

```
select TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(hi.data, 'yyyy/MM/dd 
hh24:Mi:ss'),'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 
'AMERICA/SAO_PAULO', 'dd/mm/yyyy') as data, 
sum(hi.Peso) as PesoHorario
from tabela hi where  
hi.data >= to_date('01/04/2019 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and 
hi.data < to_date('03/04/2019 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and
TO_CHAR(hi.data,'HH24MI') BETWEEN '0000' AND '0759'
group by ...
order by ...
```

**CONSULTA COM A COLUNA EXTRA**

```
select TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(hi.data, 'yyyy/MM/dd 
hh24:Mi:ss'),'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 
'AMERICA/SAO_PAULO', 'dd/mm/yyyy') as data, 
sum(hi.Peso) as PesoTotal,
sum(ha.Peso) as PesoHorario
from tabela hi, tabela ha where  
hi.data >= to_date('01/04/2019 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and 
hi.data < to_date('03/04/2019 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and
ha.data >= to_date('01/04/2019 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and 
ha.data < to_date('03/04/2019 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and
TO_CHAR(ha.data,'HH24MI') BETWEEN '0000' AND '0759'
group by ...
order by ...
```

Comment: Como você está acumulando coisas diferentes utilize uma sub-consulta para esta coluna extra.

Comment: Ou uma function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize um CASE dentro da função SUM:

```
select TO_CHAR(FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(hi.data, 'yyyy/MM/dd 
hh24:Mi:ss'),'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 
'AMERICA/SAO_PAULO', 'dd/mm/yyyy') as data, 
sum(hi.Peso) as PesoTotal,
sum(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(hi.data,'HH24MI') BETWEEN '0000' AND '0759' THEN hi.Peso ELSE 0 END) as PesoHorario
from tabela hi where  
hi.data >= to_date('01/04/2019 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and 
hi.data < to_date('03/04/2019 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') and
group by ...
order by ...
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Com uma edição na estrutura do CASE o código funcionou.